# picture gallery with small thumbnails, medium size image and full size lightbox view

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, gallery

Is there any javascript, css, ajax product gallery (even paid) that would have image (e.g. 400x300) with 5-6 thumbnails (e.g. 80x60) and lightbox (800x600) when the 400x300 image is clicked?

I need a gallery script like this: http://www.neosport.pl/product-pol-942-Buty-Nike-315343-101.html

Comment: Have you tried Google? I found a bunch of jQuery/JS scripts that offer this functionality.

Comment: shadowbox, lightbox, nyromodal etc... just google for jquery gallery. Happy hunting ;)

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of javascript galleries. I tried almost all of them, but non of them has all described funcionality ;/ If there is no such gallery with all this funcionality. Maybe some already know such script. If no then I should write such script on my own :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer on my own.
The simplest solution is to use css gallery from: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/css-multiple-image-viewer-thumbnails/ and then for big picture use any lightbox-like script (I used shadowbox with jQuery adapter from http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html)